# X-Content-Type-Options nosniff meta tag prevent image from loading

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer-9, meta-tags

When I apply the X-Content-Type-Options nosniff meta tag to my ASP.NET MVC 3 project (via the global.asax Application_BeginRequest method), a jpeg in my web app won't load in IE9. Has anyone else had this problem?

Comment: Well, if anyone else has this problem, it was fixed by re-saving the image again (eg just open it in gimp and save it again). Something in the metadata of the image file.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to enable X-Content-Type-Options is to enable it in the webserver itself.

http://www.pwnphreak.com/blog/2012/12/13/x-content-type-optionsnosniff-header-missing/

Comment: The URL is now dead, so the benefit of your answer has vanished.  In the future, please include the relevant details in addition to citing the URL.